# Spring Boot Squiggly library intercept and modify request parameter before reaching controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to filters the attributes being sent in json response for multiple requests. I used Squiggly library to achieve this. Below is the config level code added to achieve this.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(ObjectMapper.class)
public class SquigglyAutoconfigure {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean squigglyRequestFilter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) 
    {
            Squiggly.init(objectMapper, new RequestSquigglyContextProvider());

            FilterRegistrationBean<SquigglyRequestFilter> filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
            filter.setFilter(new SquigglyRequestFilter());
            filter.setOrder(1);
            return filter;
        }

}
```

Now I have a working code that responds only the fields sent in query parameters as "fields". Eg - inventory/stock?fields=stockInformation will only return field stockInformation in response.

Now, front-end can send query prameter "fields" to receive only required fields.

But I also want to define a default set of fields for each request. i.e. if front-end do not sent queryparam "fields", i should be able to initialise fields with custom values. I tried adding defaultValue in contoller but it didn't worked.

Below code didn't worked

```
@PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public StockInformation returnAllStock(@RequestBody FilterDataList filterDataList,
            @RequestParam(name = "fields", required = false,defaultValue="stockInformation{productId}") String fields)
```

Is there a way where I can intercept each request and initialise request param "fields"?

Answer (score 1):

If you intialize RequestSquigglyContextProvider, you should be able to acheive this
The key is the  `new RequestSquigglyContextProvider("fields", "id,name,caption")`

Example code

```
Squiggly.init(mapper, new RequestSquigglyContextProvider("fields", "id,name,caption") {
    @Override
    protected String customizeFilter(String filter, HttpServletRequest request, Class beanClass) {

        if (filter != null && Page.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
            filter = "**,content[" + filter + "]";
        }

        return filter;
    }
});
```